Saturation of ParametricPlot and RegionPlot
Consider these two examples
ParametricPlot[{x, y}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> HatchFilling[]]
RegionPlot[ParametricRegion[{x, y}, {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}}],PlotStyle -> HatchFilling[]]

and focus on the saturation of the two hatchings. The outputs like like:
 
The first hatching is notably lighter than the second. How can I make the hatching in ParametricPlot as saturated as in RegionPlot?
Note on usecase:
I want to combine both in my more complicated plot and want the hatching to match. It is currently way easier for me to change hatching of ParametricPlot than in RegionPlot (just for the shear number of times I have used RegionPlot). And even if I could circumvent this problem, I am rather curious as to why this happens and how to solve it.

PlotStyle -> Directive@{Opacity[1], HatchFilling[]}

PlotStyle -> HatchFilling[1, 3] in parametricPlot gives appox. the same hatching.

@cvgmt Turns out this is the case. Should you turn your comment into an (indeed rather simple, yet useful in my opinion) answer, I will accept it. Do you happen to be aware why the default value of Opacity is not 1. for ParametricPlot but apparently is for RegionPlot?

ParametricPlot and RegionPlot use different default setting for PlotStyle and BoundaryStyle. So if you want them to be the same you have to override each default value that they do not have the same with your own explicit value.
PlotStyle -> HatchFilling[] is not enough since they use different defalut values of Opacity[] and also for example FaceForm[Opacity[]].
If the same BoundaryStyle and PlotStyle are explicitly used for both plots they are unrecognizable from each other (which can be seen on image difference).
ps = Directive[AbsoluteThickness[1.6`], FaceForm[Opacity[1]], 
   ColorData[97, 1], Opacity[1], 
   HatchFilling[Times[Rational[1, 4], Pi]]];
bs = AbsoluteThickness[1.6`];


ParametricPlot[{x, y}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, BoundaryStyle -> bs, 
 PlotStyle -> ps, Frame -> False, Axes -> False, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, PlotRangePadding -> 0.05, 
 ImagePadding -> 0, ImageSize -> Small]

RegionPlot[ParametricRegion[{x, y}, {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}}], 
 BoundaryStyle -> bs, PlotStyle -> ps, Frame -> False, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, PlotRangePadding -> 0.05, 
 ImagePadding -> 0, ImageSize -> Small]

ImageDifference[%% // Rasterize, % // Rasterize]

Clear[bs, ps]




I belive this is not the case. At least for me
ParametricPlot[{x, y}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1},   PlotStyle -> HatchFilling[], BoundaryStyle -> None] vs.
RegionPlot[ParametricRegion[{x, y}, {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}}],   PlotStyle -> HatchFilling[], BoundaryStyle -> None]
looks different in either case yet fullfills your assumptions. It turns out default value of Opacity option is different in either case, only authors of Mathematica know why.

Take some effort and read the answer properly. All the values have to be given explicitly. So no HatchFilling[] but explicitly use values like HatchFilling[Times[Rational[1, 4], Pi]](and all other values of AbsoluteThickness, FaceForm, color and Opacity).

Interesting. By explicitly using BoundaryStyle I would imagine just including BoundaryStyle->anything. I would describe what you (likely) mean as "explicitly specify ?all/which? parameters of ?all/which? options of (say) BoundaryStyle". Or do you mean "you need to specify all options as presented in the answer?"

Playing with mathematica further I realized what you were trying to achieve. If you restructure your answer so that it first separetely shows how to make the hatching same (which is the original question) and than mention how to make the plots identical (noting importance of the additional parameters) I will accept it. Or I can open another question along the lines "How to make RegionPlot and ParametricPlot look identical."

@P.L. I consider my answer good as it is, nevertheless I added three explanation sentences at the beginning.
